tikz markdown chunk breaks chunk run below in rstudio
I am writing an rmarkdown document, including a tikz chunk.  In rstudio, chunks after the tikz chunk cannot be run.  I have replicated the problem in the default Rmd file created by Rstudio.

Code here:
---
title: "Test"
author: "my name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Draw a Tikz Figure

```{tikz, Protest_Hybrid_Fig, echo=FALSE, fig.width=5,fig.height=5,fig.caption='Test tikz chunk'}
%
% Draw a tikz figure representing the hybrid relationships
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid(10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}

```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.



The document knits fine.  However, cannot work on chunks independently of knitting entire document.


You are using latex, and having your output file be html_document, when I updated mine to be a pdf_document, I got a tikz graph in the middle of the report, I also did html_document output and got the same chart as below. I also did this setting for tikz before running options(tikzDefaultEngine = "xetex") not sure if that helped, but might be worth looking into the devices for Rmarkdon "tikz" does have its own device
---
title: "tikz"
output:
  pdf_document: default
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{tikz}
  - \usepackage{pgfplots}
---
```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Draw a Tikz Figure

```{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid(10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
```
## Including Plots
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```


